Flutter android build issue post flutter update
build and run works fine but in release build, I started finding issue:
ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in /Users/chiragjuneja/Documents/work/playground/yashutales/badminton_score_tracker/build/flutter_inappwebview_android/outputs/mapping/release/missing_rules.txt.
ERROR: R8: Missing class android.window.BackEvent (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.startBackGesture(android.window.BackEvent) and 3 other contexts)

Solved:
After some more googling and trying out various suggestions, this worked for me.
buildTypes {
        release { 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

updating the gradle file with the above change post adding
-keep class android.window.BackEvent { *; }

in proguard-rules.pro that I created for this only.
And I changed plugin details
from
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

to
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

Hope it helps someone else too.

The error is pretty clear: Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in. Did you try doing what it recommends?

The missing class was added in API level 34, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/BackEvent. Please ensure that you are using the Android U or later Platform SDK. Using the -dontwarn rules generated into .../missing_rules.txt is not recomended in this case.

After some more googling and trying out various suggestions, this worked for me.
buildTypes {
        release { 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

updating the gradle file with the above change post adding
-keep class android.window.BackEvent { *; }

in proguard-rules.pro that I created for this only.
And I changed plugin details from
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

to
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

Hope it helps someone else too.

The missing classes are related to Android and could be due to R8 shrinking essential code. To address this:
Navigate to your Flutter project’s android directory and open the proguard-rules.pro file.
If you don’t have this file, create one under android/app directory
-keep class android.window.BackEvent { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity { *; }

Run flutter pub upgrade to update all Flutter dependencies.
Ensure your flutter_inappwebview plugin is up to date. You can do this by checking the latest version of flutter_inappwebview and updating your pubspec.yaml
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk --release


Adding keep rules like -keep class android.window.BackEvent { *; } has no effect on the missing classes error. Classes reported as missing are already missing on input to the compilation. The missing class was added in API level 34, see developer.android.com/reference/android/window/BackEvent, so this is most likely caused by using a Platform SDK from Android T or earlier.

It did not work for me.
